# Proving $\alpha\colon S\to T$ is one-to-one if $\alpha(A\cap B)=\alpha(A)\cap\alpha(B)$, where $A,B\subseteq S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Prove that $\alpha\colon S\to T$ is one-to-one if $\alpha(A\cap B)=\alpha(A)\cap\alpha(B)$.

**Book solution:** Assume that $\alpha(A\cap B)=\alpha(A)\cap\alpha(B)$ for every pair of subsets $A$ and $B$ of $S$. If $\alpha(x_1)=\alpha(x_2)$ for $x_1,x_2\in S$, then with $A=\{x_1\}$ and $B=\{x_2\}$ we have $\alpha(A)\cap\alpha(B)=\{\alpha(x_1)\}=\{\alpha(x_2)\}$, and so $\alpha(A\cap B)=\{\alpha(x_1)\}=\{\alpha(x_2)\}$, whence $A=B$ and $x_1=x_2$; thus, $\alpha$ is one-to-one.

**Question:** The proof supplied by my book...does it seem adequate? Appears to be a little fishy to me because $A$ and $B$ are both restricted to be singleton sets even though they needn't be. I thought about reworking the proof as follows...is my revised proof better / more correct or is it flawed?

**Reworked proof:** Suppose that $I$ and $J$ are sets of indices and that $Q$ is the set of indices for elements $x_q$ in $S$; that is, $S=\{x_q : q\in Q\}$. Furthermore, suppose that $I\cup J=Q$ and $I\cap J=\varnothing$ and
$$
(\forall i\in I)(\forall j\in J)(i\neq j\land X_I = \{x_i : i\in I\}\land X_J=\{x_j : j\in J\}).
$$
Then we may let $A=X_I=\{x_i\}$ and $B=X_J=\{x_j\}$.

If $\alpha(x_i)=\alpha(x_j)$ for $x_i,x_j\in S$, then with $A=\{x_i\}$ and $B=\{x_j\}$, we have $\alpha(A)\cap\alpha(B)=\{\alpha(x_i)\}=\{\alpha(x_j)\}$, and so $\alpha(A\cap B)=\{\alpha(x_i)\}=\{\alpha(x_2)\}$ whereby we see that $A=B$ and $x_i=x_j$ for all $i\in I$ and $j\in J$. Thus, $\alpha$ is one-to-one.

Is this correct? Is it overkill? Would love to get some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof in your book is perfectly fine.  The property $\alpha(A\cap B)=\alpha(A)\cap\alpha(B)$ is much stronger than is needed to prove one-to-one-ness.  A weaker version where $A,B$ are restricted to singletons is plenty (as you observed).

The reworked proof builds a lot of machinery defining $A,B$ to each be "half" of the domain $S$, but then in the last paragraph switches to singleton sets again.

Perhaps it was meant that $A=X_I$ rather than $A=\{x_i\}$; the former is the half-domain as defined above, the latter is a singleton.  Under this change, we do not know that $\alpha(A)\cap \alpha(B)=\{\alpha(x_i)\}$, only that $\alpha(A)\cap\alpha(B)\supseteq \{\alpha(x_i)\}$, as there may be other "collisions" among elements in the two half-spaces.  However we do know that $\alpha(A\cap B)=\emptyset$, since $A\cap B=\emptyset$. (presumably this is part of the way that functions are defined on sets for you).  Hence you can still get a contradiction, with a lot of unnecessary machinery developed along the way.

Comment: Interesting modification/edit--so my proof introduces some things that may be incorrect and also develops unnecessary machinery as you put it. I just find it odd that $A$ and $B$ are restricted to singleton sets..but that doesn't bastardize the proof by the book then hm?

Comment: Also, in order to define the two half-domains A,B, you may need some version of the [axiom of choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice), since the domain could be very large.  After all, how do you decide which of the two sets each domain element goes into?  The book's proof doesn't have this issue.

Comment: You're right--I think my issue here may have been perhaps reading too much into the definition of a one-to-one mapping? And then running off and creating problematic assessments. Does that sound like a fair assessment?